# Help implementing quick sort

Tags: c, sorting, quicksort

This is what I have and it doesn't work. Can't figure out why... The problem is probably in the quick_sort function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void quick_sort(int * a, int l, int r);
void swap(int * a, int i, int j);

int main(void)
{
  #define N 10
  int a[N], i;
  for (i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    a[i] = rand();
    printf("%d\n", a[i]);
  }
  quick_sort(a, 0, N - 1);
  for (i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    printf("%d\n", a[i]);
  return 0;
  #undef N
}

void quick_sort(int * a, int l, int r)
{
  int i, j;
  if (l < r) {
    swap(a, rand() % (r - l + 1), r);
    i = l;
    for (j = l; j < r; ++j)
      if (a[j] < a[r]) {
        swap(a, i, j);
        ++i;
      }
    swap(a, i, r);
    quick_sort(a, l, i - 1);
    quick_sort(a, i + 1, r);
  }
}

void swap(int * a, int i, int j)
{
  int k;
  k = a[i];
  a[i] = a[j];
  a[j] = k;
}
```

Comment: In what way doesn't it work...?

Comment: Please provide your `dataset`, `your output` and `expected output`.

Comment: `l` is an horrible identifier. Most single-letter identifiers in many contexts are bad, but `l` in any context is just plain horrible! Consider renaming the variables (`low` and `high`; `left` and `right`, `llim` and `rlim`, ...)

Comment: razlebe, hari. Solved. But thanks anyway. pmg. Yeah, generally. But it's not a problem on my editor and this is just a toy implementation.

Comment: `l` is only horrible if you use horrible fonts...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fix this line: `swap(a, rand() % (r - l + 1), r);`

Should be: `swap(a, l + rand() % (r - l + 1), r);`

Comment: Thanks, that solves it! And at first I thought that `l` was a `1`...