# Quicksort Algorithm not assigning pivot correctly

Tags: java, sorting, quicksort

I watched this fantastic visualization of a quick sort algorithm: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z5nSXTnD1I4

I felt I really understood the principles behind quick sort and, with the help of some guides online, set about creating my own quick sort.
This is what I came up with:

```
public void quickSort(int[] a, int left, int right) {

    int index = partition(a, left, right);
    if (left < index - 1)
      quickSort(a, left, index);
    if (index < right)
      quickSort(a, index + 1, right);
}

private int partition (int[] a, int left, int right) {
    int i = left - 1;
    int j = right + 1;
    int pivot = a[0];

    while (i < j) {

        i++;

        while (a[i] < pivot)
            i++;

        j--;

        while (a[j] > pivot)
            j--;

        if (i < j)
            swap (a, i, j);
    }
return i;
}   

private void swap (int[] a, int i, int j) {
    int temp = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = temp;
}
```

The values of left and right are the following:

```
left = 0
right = array size - 1
```

Unfortunately the output isn't correct. The problem appears to lie in my treatment of the pivot. In the visualization I watched, the instructor physically removed the pivot and left the pointer pointing at nothing. He carried on with the tutorial and when he got to the point where i and j (what I call left and right) both pointed at the same empty spot, he inserted the pivot and carried on.

As I am physically keeping the pivot in place, I am finding it difficult to properly sort it.

In this code, I am working with the input:

```
4 8 1 6 3 7 2 5
```

I get the output:

```
1 3 2 6 8 7 4 5
```

Once the "4" value (i.e. the pivot) is sorted at the very start of the algorithm, I never resort it, which throws everything off. Additionally, I think there is something wrong with the quickSort method.

Could someone give me a few pointers? Thanks.

**Edit: Two edits that were here have been removed as they contained unnecessary and incorrect information. One of them changed the pivot to: (left + right) / 2. This was of course wrong for the reasons explained in the answers below.**

Comment: Closing as too localized.

Comment: @djechlin: I thought it targetted a specific programming algorithm, as per the FAQ. If I'm wrong, could you recommend which Stack Exchange to ask this on?

Comment: @djechlin he is asking a coding problem showing code. How can that be too localized??

Comment: @djechlin Haven't decided whether I quite agree in this case, but at least wait a while so the question has a chance to be answered.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen "This question is unlikely to help future visitors," because future visitors are unlikely to have a problem with "'my' code", where "my" means "Andrew Martin's."  Future visitors will likely post nearly the same question because they have a slightly different problem.  E.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905554/help-implementing-quick-sort, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13394014/implementation-of-quick-sort, etc.

Comment: @djechlin: I would point out that in the FAQ it states: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face." I don't see where". As already asked, if you know of another Stack Exchange site where I should post this, please do recommend it.

Comment: @AndrewMartin see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask -> "make it relevant to others."  If this cannot be done then this is not appropriate for any StackExchange.  Obviously this is my opinion of SE's policies and other commenters disagree with me, but in any case I encourage you to develop the skill of making questions relevant to others - *because* if your question is relevant to others you will have formulated it in a way that lets you search for help from others who have done the same with a similar problem.

Comment: @djechlin You got it wrong.  It is perfectly alright to ask an actual coding problem on stack overflow.  I think perhaps you are thinking of programmers.SE.  In any case feel free to ask on Meta to clarify.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen you got it - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168775/is-the-too-localized-description-inconsistent-with-the-communitys-de-facto-st

Comment: @djechlin: It will be interesting to see what they say over at meta. I understand your logic, but if that rule was applied that strictly, I'd argue half the posts on SO would be gotten rid of, as many of them are extremely specific to a very small thing.

Comment: @AndrewMartin - see meta link in above comment (in case you missed)

Comment: @djechlin: I saw it - that's why I commented. Thanks

Comment: @djechlin: Just to let you know I've amended the question title now an answer has been given. Hopefully it'll be clear to people who may search for a similar issue in the future.

Comment: @AndrewMartin that's an immense improvement, and if I were being more savvy I would have looked for that edit rather than vote to close.  This now seems more consistent with Kate's post in the meta thread in which a question turns out to potentially be more general than it sounded at first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to get rid of partition, because you need both `i` and `j`. It should look like this:

```
public void quickSort(int[] a, int left, int right) {

    int i = left; // Was -1 
    int j = right; // Was +1
    int pivot = a[left + (right - left) / 2]; // Pivot is the value of the middle index, not the index itself
    while (i <= j) { // Changed terminating condition
        //   i++;  Not needed
        while (a[i] < pivot) { 
            i++;
        }
        //    j++; Not needed
        while (a[j] > pivot) {
            j--;
        }
        if (i <= j) {  // Changed terminating condition
            swap(a, i, j);
            i++;  // You need to progress the indexes after the swap
            j--;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
    if (left < j) {  // Changed condition
        quickSort(a, left, j);
    }
    if (i < right) { 
        quickSort(a, i, right); // was i + 1
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 7, 6, 8]
[1, 5, 4, 2, 3, 7, 6, 8]
[1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 7, 6, 8]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 6, 8]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 6, 8]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: Works perfectly. You sir, are an absolute legend. I'll study the differences between your code and mine and try and learn from it.

Comment: No problem. Comment here if you need any clarifications.

Comment: Hi, Can you explain this line a bit further ? int pivot = a[left + (right - left) / 2];

Comment: @OliverCiappara That line means that we select as the value of `pivot` the element that lies in the middle between `left` and `right`.

Answer (score 2):

well obviously that you have got your accepted answer. however I would mention that your partition logic could be implemented easier, with only one for (or while) loop, without nest loop either:

```
int partition(final int[] a, final int left, final int right) {
        // set the last element as pivot
        final int pivot = a[right];
        int i = left - 1, j = left;
        for (; j < right; j++) 
            if (a[j] < pivot) {
                i++;
                swap(a, i, j);
            }       
        // swap a[i+1] and pivot
        swap(a, i + 1, right);
        return i + 1;
    }
```

and in your quickSort method:

```
if (left < index)
  quickSort(a, left, index-1);
if (index < right)
  quickSort(a, index + 1, right);
```

hope it helps

Comment: It all helps. I'll study this and try and learn from it. Thank you

Comment: @AndrewMartin `, j = left` - it's there

Comment: @AndrewMartin no I don't need `int j`, it was declared before the for loop. read the codes, dude.

Comment: Apologies - I had NO idea you could declare a for loop like that. Sorry for the silly suggestion and thanks again for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
int pivot = a[0];
```

should be

```
int pivot = a[left];
```

That, with changing `swap (a, i, j);` to `swap (a, i--, j++);` and [everything appears to work fine](http://ideone.com/27kE5r).

**Why the above change:**

The pivot should be the first element in the range, not the first element.

Nor should it be in this middle, as here:

```
int pivot = a[(left + right) / 2];
```

It doesn't matter which element you want the pivot to be, the easiest is to always swap the chosen element with the first element, and continue as normal. There may be other ways of doing things, but those would likely be more complicated.

So you can say:

```
swap(left, (left + right) / 2);
int pivot = a[left];
```

which is very similar to the above (not identical), just a whole lot easier to deal with.

Comment: Someone else recommended pivot = a[left + (right - left) / 2], which I think meets the median of three rule.
However, this is what I really intended to do in the first place, and of course totally got wrong. Thanks for this.

Comment: @AndrewMartin `a[left + (right - left) / 2]` - **this is not median of 3** (not even close). For the median of 3, find the median of the first, middle and last elements, and **swap that element with the element in the first position**, then continue as normal.

Comment: Just googled median of three and realised how wrong I was. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the `partition` method should return `j` instead of `i`.

Another problem in your code are your stop conditions :

instead of two separate conditions I'd change it to a single condition :

```
if (left < right)  {

  do partition & recursive calls

}
```

The full code :

```
public void quickSort(int[] a, int left, int right) {
    if (left < right) {
      int index = partition(a, left, right);
      quickSort(a, left, index);
      quickSort(a, index + 1, right);
    }
}

private int partition (int[] a, int left, int right) {
    int i = left - 1;
    int j = right + 1;
    int pivot = a[(left+right)/2];

    while (i < j) {

        i++;

        while (a[i] < pivot)
            i++;

        j--;

        while (a[j] > pivot)
            j--;

        if (i < j)
            swap (a, i, j);
    }
    return j;
}   

private void swap (int[] a, int i, int j) {
    int temp = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = temp;
}
```

Comment: It could need that, but unfortunately that returns a StackOverflow error - likely due to a mistake elsewhere.

Comment: You should apply that change to your original code. Your change in edit2 is wrong.You must change i & j before the loop, since they are initialized to values just outside the range of the array you are partitioning.

Comment: I've changed my personal copy back to before edit2 and changed the return int to j - however, it still generates a StackOverflow error

Comment: Do you have a debugger? StackOverflow means the partition method doesn't partition the input (i.e. one of the partitions is empty), which causes an infinite recursion.

Comment: Yeah, I'm going through each step now on the Eclipse debugger (using your edits). Just can't figure out how to stop the error!

Comment: I hope that in the first edit you meant to say `pivot = a[(left + right) / 2]` and not `pivot = (left + right) / 2`

Comment: Actually, I did notice it, but had already changed some other code as well. Removing those changes and doing this has also fixed it. Thank you for your answer Eran, this was extremely helpful.