# I'm not sure what's wrong with my partition function

Tags: java, debugging, sorting

Eclipse keeps on telling me that there's something wrong with my partition function. It's in java and is part of a class that's all about sorting arrays.

A partition works like this: There are two indices i and j  in an array and at the very beginning of the partition algorithm i points to the first element in the array and j points to the last one. Then algorithm moves i forward, until an element with value greater or equal to the pivot is found. Index j is moved backward, until an element with value lesser or equal to the pivot is found. If i ≤ j then they are swapped and i steps to the next position (i + 1), j steps to the previous one (j - 1). Algorithm stops, when i becomes greater than j.

Can you see what the problem is, because I'm having trouble finding it. The help would be much appreciated.

```
public static int partition(int arr[], int left, int right)
    {
        int x = arr[right];

        int i = left-1;
        int temp=0;

        for (int j=left; j<right; j++)
        {
            if(arr[j]<=x)
            {
                i++;
                temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;

            }
        }

        temp = arr[i+1];
        arr[i+1] = arr[right];
        arr[right] = temp;
        return (i+1);

    }
```

EDIT

Eclipse is saying that there are two problems, one with this line of code in the partition function:

```
int x = arr[right];
```

And with this line of my test class:

```
sort.partition(array, 100, array.length);
```

Here is the test class, which includes functions I haven't mentioned.

```
import java.util.Random;


public class test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int size = 1000;
        int max = 5000; 
        int[] array = new int[size];
        int loop = 0; 

        Random generator = new Random();
        //Write a loop that generates 1000 integers and 
        //store them in the array using generator.nextInt(max)

        generator.nextInt(max); //generating one

        //I need to generate 1000
        //So I need some kind of loop that will generate 1000 numbers. 

        for (int i =0; i<1000; i++)
        {
            generator.nextInt(max);
        }



        /**
         * After I do this, I'll have the array, array. 
         * Then comes what's under this. 
         * THat method is for measuring the time.
         * System.currentTimeMillis();, 
         * with this, I can collect a time for the start of the method
         * and one for the end. 
         * Time at the end, minus the time at the start
         * gets us the running time. 
         */



        long result;

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        sort.quickSort(array,  100,  array.length-1);
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        result = endTime-startTime; 

        System.out.println("The quick sort runtime is " + result + " miliseconds");

        long result2;

        long startTime2 = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
        sort.partition(array, 100, array.length);
        long endTime2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        result2 =  endTime2 - startTime2;
        System.out.println("The partition runtime is "+result2 + " miliseconds");

        long result3;

        long startTime3 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        sort.bubbleSort(array, 100);
        long endTime3 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        result3 = endTime3-startTime3;
        System.out.println("The bubble sort runtime is "+result3 + " miliseconds");

        long result4;

        long startTime4 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        sort.selectionSort(array, 100); //change the second number to change
        //the size of an array. 
        long endTime4 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        result4 = endTime4-startTime4;
        System.out.println("The selection sort runtime is "+result4 + " miliseconds");



    }

}
```

Comment: What does Eclipse say is wrong with it?

Comment: You can find some working examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15045481/quicksort-algorithm-not-assigning-pivot-correctly/15046006#15046006).

Comment: I ran it again and it said this:

Comment: I didn't realize pressing enter would post the comment. Here:     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1000
 at sort.partition(sort.java:48)
 at test.main(test.java:59)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you aren't actually storing the random numbers in the array, so it will be all zeros.

As for the actual error you're seeing, you've got a classic off by one error. You have two choices: make `right` point to the end of the array or one past the end of the array. Either one is valid, but you're mixing the two.

Specifically, you're passing 1000, one past the end of the array, for the `right` value, but then you immediately index the array with it, naturally throwing an exception.

Comment: Never mind. Thanks to your advice I figured it out and got rid of the errors, but you're also right about how my arrays are empty. Thank you for the help though.